# boost serialization hexadecimal decimal encoding of data

Tags: c++, boost, boost-serialization

I am new to boost serialization but this seems very strange to me.

I have a very simple class with two members

```
int number // always = 123

char buffer[?] // buffer with ? size
```

so sometimes I set the size to `buffer[31]` then I serialize the class

```
22 serialization::archive 8 0 0 1 1 0 0 0 0 123 0 0 31 0 0 0 65 65
```

we can see the `123` and the `31` so no issue here both are in decimal format.

now I change buffer to `buffer[1024]` so I expected to see

```
22 serialization::archive 8 0 0 1 1 0 0 0 0 123 0 0 1024 0 0 0 65 65 ---
```

this is the actual outcome

```
22 serialization::archive 8 0 0 1 1 0 0 0 0 123 0 0 0 4 0 0 65 65 65
```

boost has switched to hex for the buffer size only?

notice the other value is still decimal.

So what happens if I switch number from 123 to 1024 ?

I would imagine 040 ?

```
22 serialization::archive 8 0 0 1 1 0 0 0 0 1024 0 0 0 4 0 0 65 65
```

If this is by design, why does the 31 not get converted to 1F ? its not consistent.

This causes problems in our load function for the split_free, we were doing this

```
unsigned int size;
ar >> size;
```

but as you might guess, when this is 040, it truncs to zero :(

what is the recommended solution to this?

I was using boost 1.45.0 but I tested this on boost 1_56.0 and it is the same.

EDIT: sample of the serialization function

```
template<class Archive>
void save(Archive& ar, const MYCLASS& buffer, unsigned int /*version*/) {
    ar << boost::serialization::make_array(reinterpret_cast<const unsigned char*>(buffer.begin()), buffer.length());
}
```

MYCLASS is just a wrapper on a char* with the first element an unsigned int
 to keep the length approximating a UNICODE_STRING

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/windows/desktop/aa380518(v=vs.85).aspx

The code is the same if the length is 1024 or 31 so I would not have expected this to be a problem.

Comment: You should show the code that's performing the serialization.

Comment: Edit your post and put that code up there. Make sure it's indented four spaces and it should be syntax highlighted as well. It'll make it easier for people to read and more likely for people to help.

Comment: Its like this now Steve.

Comment: I don't think Boost "switched to hex". I honestly don't have any experience with this, but it looks like boost is serializing as an array of bytes, which can only hold numbers from 0 through 255. 1024 would be a byte with a value `4` followed by a byte with the value `0`.

Comment: Hi Steve you are correct. I assumed the 04 00 was 400 hex which would be 1024 but it like you said, its actually the byte array... I should have tried some other numbers... I can fix it now. Thanks

Comment: I re-posted my comment as an answer, if you would like to accept it as such :)  Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think Boost "switched to hex". I honestly don't have any experience with this, but it looks like boost is serializing as an array of bytes, which can only hold numbers from 0 through 255. 1024 would be a byte with a value 4 followed by a byte with the value 0.

Answer (score 0):

"why does the 31 not get converted to 1F ? its not consistent" - your assumptions are creating false inconsistencies. Stop assuming you can read the serialization archive format when actually you're just guessing.

If you want to know, trace the code. If not, just use the archive format.

If you want "human accessible form", consider the xml_oarchive.